# printing variable fom a Class in Python

Tags: python

I am a newbie in Python and playing around with the classes right now,

Have a look at this simple code,

```
class Testing:

    BB_Key_Length = {256 : 240}

#method __init__() is a special method, which is called class constructor or initialization method that 
#Python calls when you create a new instance of this class.    
    def __init__(self, key_length):
        self._key_length = key_length
        self._n = int(key_length / 8)

        if key_length in self.BB_Key_Length:
            self._b = self.BB_Key_Length[key_length]
            print(self._b)


Object1 = Testing(200)
print(Testing.BB_Key_Length)
```

on line 13, it is written that, `print(self._b)` which is also inside the `__init__` function but why the value of self._b is not printing when I am creating the object

```
Object1 = Testing(200)
```

All I want is to print the value of `self._b` which i couldn't be able to print

Comment: Because of the line `if key_length in self.BB_Key_Length`. If that condition isn't met, the line `print(self._b)` never happens. And indeed, `key_length` will be equal to 200, and 200 is not in the dictionary `{256 : 240}`

Comment: but 200 is in range of 240 and 256..Why it is not printing then

Comment: That's not how dictionaries work. `if 200 in self.BB_Key_Length` just checks whether there is a *key* in `self.BB_Key_Length` equal to 200. But there is only one key in `self.BB_Key_Length`, and that is 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the value of self._b is not printing when I am creating the object `Object1 = Testing(200)`

Because the print statement is inside an if statement, which is false because 200 is not a key in the dict `self.BB_Key_Length`.

Comment: but 200 is in range of 240 and 256..Why it is not printing then

Comment: @Xufyan That's not a range. That's a dict. If you want a range, use a `range`.

Comment: @Xufyan Also, 200 is not in the range (240,256).

Comment: @Xufyan, a `dict` is a mapping, function, a container that for each key `A` returns an associated value `B`. In your case, you have defined a dictionary (`dict`) with a single key `256` of value `240`